# Custom theorem title in place

Tags: environments, theorems

I want to do something like this:

```
\begin{theorem}[Actual name of theorem]
This theorem states that...
\end{theorem}
```

and it should render:

```
Actual name of theorem. This theorem states that...
```

I changed the name of theorem by creating a theorem-like environment, but I want to do this one in line, without creating a new environment.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear from the question whether *no* new environment is to be created, on the one hand, or whether *multiple* new environments, one for each separate named theorem, are to be created.

Assuming the latter, perhaps something like this?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries,
  headindent=-0.25em,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\bfseries, 
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NOTE\thmt@space\NUMBER,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
]{namedthmstyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[
  style=namedthmstyle,
  name=Theorem,
  title = {},
  numberlike=theorem
]{namedtheorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The whole thing}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Theorem of Pythagoras]

The square on the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares other two sides.

\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Fermat's Last Theorem]

For $n > 2$, there are no positive integers $a, b, c$ for which $a^{n} + b^{n} = c^{n}$.

\end{namedtheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: Named theorems]

Note that I had to "fake" making the `namedtheorem` name typeset essentially flush with the left margin by using `headindent=-0.25em`. Surely there's a better—and more precise—way to accomplish that.